# Ignore a product for shipping rate calculation

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, fedex

Is there some way to ignore a product price and weight for the shipping rate calculation?

I´m working with the FedEx module and I don´t want FedEx to add extra shipping rate when certain products are added to the cart because I will add a specific amount to the shipping rate manually for each of the specific types of products.

Thanks!